# Correct byteoffset and complete line with grep

Tags: bash, grep, output

I want to use grep in a way that i get the exact byteoffset but still get the complete line where the matching string was found.
Right now the output looks like this:

grep-query:

```
grep -bor --include=\* abx ./
```

Result: **file path*:(correct)*byteoffset*:abx**

**or**

grep-query:

```
grep -br --include=\* abx ./
```

Result: ***file path*:(incorrect)*byteoffset*:*lineblabla...abx...blablaline***

(I removed the -o argument)

What i want is: ***file path*:(correct)*byteoffset*:*lineblabla...abx...blablaline***

I don't want to do a second grep call as my results can get quite big but still want the correct byteoffset and the full result line.

Cheers

Comment: Please format your question with code blocks, this way it's really hard to understand

Comment: That was my first question here. I hope it is now easier to understand.